# What is the best way to make sure this css works in all browsers?

Tags: css

I am taking over an application that has buttons with this css:

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #049CDB, #0064CD);
```

it looks beautiful in firefox but looks like a mess in IE, etc

what is the best way to take these clearly firefox specific css and determine the best way to make it look the same on all browsers (just need IE8+)

Comment: leora `-moz-` says it all, means it's a mozilla vendor specific prefix, to find out if you can use some property and how take a look at http://caniuse.com/. For IE8 you'll need a hack, while for other vendors, cause some properties are still in draft mode, use their prefixes like `-o-`, `-ms-`, `-webkit-` etc :) If you Goog for **CSS3 Gradient Generator** ... believe me, you'll be happy.

Comment: Search linear gradient css with Google

Comment: Any `-moz` CSS property is supposed to work only with Mozilla-derived browsers.

Comment: After 1.6K questions, you'd expect a user to know how to ask a proper question. Please freshen up on the [help] before asking more questions.

Comment: Sadly the fastest way to create a simple gradient (yes, in 2014!) is still your favorite image editor and one line of CSS `background:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This tool might be a useful tool for you.

Since this CSS attribute is still a working draft of CSS and has some legacy it will require a lot of markup to be fully supported for your current situation. The -moz- prefix is one such isntance of providing support. All other browsers will required either the standard, -ms-, -webkit-, -webkit-*type* or -o- prefix as well.

You should look out for other spots in the application you've taken over for code that hasn't been fully tested on other browsers.

**LINK**
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of opinion but there are tools online that will help you generate css for gradients that works across browsers. http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ is an example.